# Parse path multiple files and iterate multivalue or raster in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, iterator, parse

I have 2 files (rasters) (p1.img and p2.img), upon which I want that all model steps run. There are numeric steps from a to p (a, b, c, ..., etc) on the model.  I tryed two iterators: multivalue and raster iterators. The first one return the outputs correctly, for which step, but just for the file p1.img, doesn't run for the file p2.img (first image). The second one generate a kind of loop, running repeatedly and cumulatively on files originating from the landscape p1.img (second image).

I need the model run all step, only once, for files p1 and p2.

I suspect that the problem is the Parse Path tool, that in some way limit the model to run upon the first file (p1) only.

Any idea?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not particularly clear in what you are asking but just looking at your screenshots it appears you are writing output back into the folder where the input datasets are? Don't do that. Write your outputs to another folder location, this may resolve your problem at least you will be implementing best practise.

Comment: My issue is: I have two input rasters (p1.img and p2.img) and a model with many steps (outpus) chained (named "a" until "p"). I need iterate this two input files in the model. But I've tryied the multivalue iterator and raster iterator, without sucess. The first one return the outputs correctly but just in relation the file p1.img, doesn't run for the file p2.img. The second one generate a kind of loop, running repeatedly and cumulatively outputs in relation of the file p1.img. I applied your suggestion, writing output in a different folder from the inputs folder, but no effect.